# No video chat button in Discord voice channels

Tags: discord

I have set up a Discord server with several voice channels. I see no button for the video chat in the lower left corner, so it seems not to be possible to do video chat nor screen sharing. Voice is enabled: I see the microphone, headphone and settings icon.

I have gone into the Server Setting and the Roles there. For the "everyone" role I see connect, speak and video enabled. Also for another role that I have set up, these configuration setting are enabled.

I have other servers with Voice channels where I do see the "Video" and "Screen" button, it is apparently only for this particular channel.

Note a old Reddit post with a similar question: https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/aklct9/no_video_chat_button_showing_up_cant_join_video/

Answer (score 1):

I found the error myself.

It was because the channels were created as text channels rather than voice channels. I deleted the channels and created new channels as voice channels.

What might have confused me that the channels were organized in groups with the headings "Text channels" and "Voice channels". But of course these group headings do not control whether the individual channels are text or voice channels. This control seems only possible during the creation. Apparently, you cannot reconfigure the channel type.